# How to start below services in docker Entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, aws-ecs

I want to start below services when container is running.

```
sudo service celeryd start
sudo service celerybeat start 
service php7.0-fpm start 
service rsyslog start
```

Current below command is not working AWS ECS. And throwing some errors.

```
ENTRYPOINT sudo service celeryd start 
&& sudo service celerybeat start 
&& service php7.0-fpm start 
&& service rsyslog start && bash
```

Please advise me how to do it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, add the stacktrace. Also what is this `&& bash` supposed to do?

Comment: sudo is useless, as if your Dockerfile does not have a `USER xxx` directive, you are root, and as said by Ignacio `You should provide a command that doesn't end` so you may at least add at the end `&& sleep infinity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend the overall design since you are running multiple apps inside a single container. You have no error handling or feedback if any one service fails to start. That said, fixing your current problem can be done by using a command that won't exit when there is no input.

```
ENTRYPOINT service celeryd start \
 && service celerybeat start \
 && service php7.0-fpm start \
 && service rsyslog start \
 && tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: Do i need to add above entrypoint to task definition as well or just in the dockerfile will be enough ?

Comment: @user3849082 you simply replace the lines in your dockerfile with these and then rebuild your image. I'm not sure what you mean by adding to the "task definition".

Answer (score 1):

The commands you're trying to execute as entrypoint are a bash expression, so they must be executed inside a bash terminal:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sudo service celeryd start && sudo service celerybeat start && sudo service php7.0-fpm start && sudo service rsyslog start && tail -f /dev/null"]
```

Furthermore, your last command is bash so the container will end right after executing the entrypoint. You should provide a command that doesn't end

Comment: Yes and how to do it ?

Comment: The `&&` works in the default shell which processes commands when you use the string syntax. No need to use json syntax and then add a shell back manually. The lack of input to bash is the issue.

Comment: Just edited with the idea from the answer of BMitch: Use tail -f /dev/null for keeping it running forever

Comment: You're completely right about the entrypoint, no need of /bin/bash -c and JSON format

Answer (score 0):

put all commands start.sh file and give execute permission, Copy that files to docker image while building docker image

write docker file below CMD ["./start.sh"]